# Search Domain Not Working With Squid

Tags: domain-name-system, squid

I just set up a squid proxy as a parent proxy to HAVP.  When I or other users try to access a domain with an address like "http://foo" I get the following squid error in the browser:

```
The dnsserver returned:

    Server Failure: The name server was unable to process this query.
```

However, "http://foo.companyname.com" works fine.  The search domain in resolv.conf on both the client and proxy host is companyname.com. (There a better term for "search domain"?)

Is there a way to correct this, maybe something in the squid.conf file?.

Comment: Also if someone can enlighten me as to *why* it works this way, I would appreciate that as well.

Comment: Do nslookup and ping return results for your domain on the client and proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed:

```
append_domain .mycompany.com
```

in my `squid.conf` file.  (Thought I grepped through conf for domain, must have missed it the first time).